# How can I create an Ecto.Query to get the length of an array of my schema's fields?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have this schema and empty query:

```
defmodule User.User do
 use Ecto.Schema

 schema "people" do
     field(:name, :string)
     field(:jobs, {:array, :string})
     field(:devices, {:array, :string})
   end

 def count_user_structs() do
  ...
 end
end
```

and this is the result in console:

```
[
  %User.User{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "people">,
    devices: ["MacBook Air", "MacBook Pro"],
    id: 1,
    jobs: ["Frontend Developer", "Backend Developer", "Software Developer"],
    name: "Dmitri"
  }
]
```

How can I create an Ecto.Query to get the length of an arrays(jobs and devices)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using PostgreSQL, the length of the array field could be calculated with `coalesce(array_length(field, 1), 0)`.

In [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) we have [`fragment/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1).

That said, somewhat alongside below should work

```elixir
from u in User, 
    select: %{jobs: fragment("coalesce(array_length(jobs, 1), 0)")}
```

Comment: Can you give me some more tips on how best to format the string? 
My Ecto.Query code now looks like this:

`
def count_user_structs() do
    from u in User.User,
    select: %{jobs_count: fragment("coalesce(array_length(jobs, 1), 0)"), devices_count: fragment("coalesce(array_length(devices, 1), 0)")}
  end
`
And the output is the following:

`
[%{devices_count: 2, jobs_count: 3}]
`
What is the best way to format the query so that the result is the following:
`
%User{
..
devices_count: 2
jobs_count: 4
..

}
`

Thank you!

Comment: I doubt I follow. `User` struct does not have fields `×××_count`.